# How to efficiently add and remove vector values C++

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I am trying to efficiently calculate the averages from a vector.
I have a matrix (vector of vectors) where:

**row:** the days I am going back (250)

**column:** the types of things I am calculating the average of (10,000 different things)

Currently I am using `.push_back()` which essentially iterates through each row in each column and then I use `erase()` in order to remove the last value. As this method goes through all the values, my code is very slow.

I am thinking of a method linked to substitution, however I have a hard time implementing the idea, as all the values have an order (i.e. I need to remove the old value and the value I add / substitute will be the newest).

Below is my code so far.
Any ideas for a solution or guides for the right direction will be much appreciated.

```
//declaration
vector <vector<float> > vectorOne;
//initialization
vectorOne(250, vector<float>(10000, 0)),

//This is the slow method
vectorOne[column].push_back(1);//add newest value
vectorOne[column].erase(vectorOne[column].begin() + 0); //remove latest value
```

Comment: Sounds like you want [`deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque).

Comment: This is really unclear - are you just trying to implement a circular buffer for a fixed-width sliding window?

Comment: If this is close to your actual code then of course it is going to be really slow.  `vectorOne(250, vector<float>(10000, 0)),` constructs a vector with 250x10000 elements already constructed and set to 0.  When you use `push_back` you add a 501st element.  Then `vectorOne[column].erase(vectorOne[column].begin() + 0);` is going to erase the first column which is a default 0 so now you have to shuffle forward 9999 elements.  Why are you even erasing elements?  Also you should just be accessing and storing to the vector with `[]` like `vectorOne[10][25] = someval;`.

Comment: `push_back()` does not iterate through the values, it adds extra values to the end.

Comment: @Galik yes, true. However when I erase, then all elements are moved, correct?

Comment: @Newskooler with a `vector`, yes. With `std::deque`, no - a deque lets you very quickly add elements to the beginning and end, but is slower to iterate through as the data are not stored contiguously in memory.

Comment: I am looking into `deque` now it may be what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a different data structure.

The problem sounds like a queue. You add to the end and take from the front. With real queues, everyone then shuffles up a step. With computer queues, we can use a circular buffer (you do need to be able to get a reasonable bound on maximum queue length).

I suggest implementing your own on top of a plain C array first, then using the STL version when you've understood the principle.